# Help me with my selector, the ID is dynamically changing every page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scan a website using jQuery, but the ID is constantly changing, but there's a permanent pattern for the ID that I'm searching for:

```
app7019261521_the_coinb4678bc2
app7019261521_the_coind42fgr23
app7019261521_the_coing0992gvb
app7019261521_the_coin12e5d0aa
```

The IDs always starts with app7019261521_the_coin

But my problem is I don't know how to put that in jQuery selector.

```
$("#app7019261521_the_coin")
```

Doesn't seem to work

So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("[id^=app7019261521_the_coin]")
```

Should work - but its MUCH slower selector than knowing the real ID - or assigning a class.  This selector will scan every element on the page one at a time, there is no good way for this selector to be optimizied.   9 times out of 10 though you could build a better selector:  Is this `#app7019...` element the direct child of another element that is easier to determine? like a `id='container'`?

```
$("#conainter > [id^=app7019261521_the_coin]"); for instance
```

From the [jQuery Selector Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

> ```
> [attribute^=value]    Returns: Array<Element(s)>
> Matches elements that have the specified attribute and it starts 
> with a certain value.
> ```

Comment: -1 as this answer was already provided. Please up-vote others who answer first.

Comment: @Jonathan, so what? they're not identical answers, don't tell people how to vote

Comment: cont: for the record, this answer is better because it explains *why* it works. That's probably why it took him a couple more minutes to post it.

Comment: @jonathan: both the other answers incorrectly assume that the item he is looking for is a div, or that its even needed to specify the tag type - plus my answer was a few minutes later because i went and found the selector documentation and explained what it was doing

Comment: none of the answers here are incorrect. but i agree that this answer is more explicit. i voted for it and i posted the first response :)

Answer (score 2):

can you set a class and just call it by a class name?

you may also be able to try

```
$("div[id^=app7019261521_the_coin]")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will find all div's that start with *app7019261521_the_coin*

Replace div with whatever element type you are searching for.

```
$j('div[id^=app7019261521_the_coin]')
```

Remember this is not very optimal, as it causes the script to check the id attribute of every matched element.

You might want to see how you can add a class to the element or at least find the parent element first and traverse from there.

Comment: -1 as this answer was already provided. Please up-vote others who answer first.

Comment: Downvote? Is it my fault that StackOverflow didnt show me the other answers when I wrote mine?  Great having you around, Jonathan.